# Correspondence between one-parameter subgroups of $G$ and $T_eG$

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, lie-algebra, vector-fields

I am reading the proof of this theorem from Andreas Arvanitoyeorgos and I cannot get some points in it, highlighted below.

**Theorem.** The map $\phi \to d\phi_0(1)$ defines a one-to-one correspondence between one-parameter subgroups of $G$ and $T_eG$.

**Proof.** Let $v \in T_eG$ and $X^v_g=(dL_g)_e(v)$ be (the value of) the corresponding left-invariant vector field.

We need to find a smooth homomorphism $\phi_v: \mathbb R \to G$.

Let $\phi: I \to G$ be the unique integral curve of $X^v$ such that $\phi(0)=e$ and $d\phi_t=X^v_{\phi(t)}$.

This curve is a homomorphism because if we fix an $s \in I$ such that $s+t \in I$ for all $t \in I$ then the curves

$$t \to \phi(s+t)$$

and

$$t \to \phi(s)\phi(t)$$

satisfy the previous equation (the second curve by the left-invariance of $X^v$), and take the common value $\phi(s)$ when $t=0$. By uniqueness of the integral curve then

$$\phi(s+t)=\phi(s)\phi(t)$$

where $s,t \in I$.

Extend to $\mathbb R$ and define $\phi_v(t)=\phi(t/n)^n$.

The map $v \to \phi_v$ is the inverse of $\phi \to d\phi_0(1)$ and this completes the proof.

***So my questions are these:***

1. We need to find a smooth homomorphism $\phi_v: \mathbb R \to G$. ***(Why?)***

   *In particular this part is not clear to me: The map $v \to \phi_v$ is the inverse of $\phi \to d\phi_0(1)$ and this completes the proof.*
2. The map $t \to \phi(s)\phi(t)$ satisfies the integral equation of the vector field by the left-invariance of $X^v$ ***(Why?)***

   I see that given the left-invariant vector field we can have 
   $dL_{\phi(s)}X^v_{\phi(t)}=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$
   and $d(\phi(s)\phi(t))=Y_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$

   But I cannot get it that $Y_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$ so that we have 
   $d(\phi(s)\phi(t))=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$ to say that $\phi(s)\phi(t)$ is the same integral curve.
3. **(What 1 in $d\phi_0(1)$ here refer to? Is it $n=1$?)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) One way to show that a map constitutes a 1-1 correspondence is by showing that it has an inverse. This is what is done here: elements of $T_eG$ are tangent vectors to $G$ at the unit element, and one-parameter subgroups of $G$ are smooth homomorphisms $\mathbb R\to G$. Note that this is a notion more general than a closed 1-dimensional subgroup, for which the theorem wouldn't hold.
The inverse should map elements of $T_eG$ to 1-parameter subgroups.

2) An integral curve is a curve that is everywhere tangent to a given vector field. From existence and unicity theorems of ordinary differential equations we get that through every point there is a unique integral curve. $\phi$ is the unique integral curve that passes through $e$ at $t = 0$, so $\phi(0) = e$ and $\dot\phi(0) \equiv d\phi_0 = X^v_e$. If instead we denote this curve $\Phi^e$, and more generally $\Phi^g$ for the unique integral curve that passes through $g$ at $t = 0$, then clearly we have $\Phi^{\phi(s)}(t) = \phi(s + t)$. The translated curve $g\phi$ passing through $g$ at $t = 0$ is an integral curve of the translated vector field, which is the same vector field by translation invariance, so it must be the unique integral curve passing through $g$. Now take $g = \phi(s)$.

3) In physics this would often just be written $\dot\phi(0)$, but strictly speaking, since $\phi$ is a smooth map $\mathbb R\to G$, its derivative in 0 is a map from the tangent space of $\mathbb R$ at 0, which is $\mathbb R$ again, to the tangent bundle of $G$ at $\phi(0) = e$, i.e. $T_eG$. Evaluating this in $1\in\mathbb R$ (or if you prefer $1\in T_0\mathbb R$) gives an element of $T_eG$. You could take any other fixed non-zero element, if you adapt your construction of $\phi_v$ accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @doetoe. All clear now. Can you explain more your last line. How to adapt the construction for other non-zero elements?

Comment: @VictorVahidiMotti I corrected a small typo: where I wrote $\dot\phi(1)$ I should have said $\dot\phi(0)$. More generally, $d\phi_0(\alpha)$ corresponds to $\dot\phi(0)\alpha$. If you take such an $\alpha\ne1$ you can construct $\phi_v$ as before, only now the inverse of the map is given by the map $v\mapsto \phi_{\alpha^{-1}v}$

Comment: Thanks again. Two related questions. So 1 here refers to the tangent vector at point 0 in R. But so is any other real number because 1 is the basis of the tangent space of R at 0, right? And we define the differential as a smooth function between tangent spaces of manifolds, I mean the definition of the differential of a one-parameter subgroup in its general Lie group sense. I see that for the one-parameter subgroup one can use the notion of differential as defined in calculus but again we take differential as defined in Lie groups, a function between two tangent spaces, right?

Comment: @VictorVahidiMotti The first question: correct.

Comment: The second: the total derivative of a map $\Phi:X\to Y$ between manifolds/Lie groups at a point $x\in X$ is a linear map $D_x\Phi$ of $d\Phi_x$ from the tangent space at $x$ to the tangent space at the image point $\Phi(x)$. The total derivative $D\Phi$ itself is a smooth function between what are called the tangent bundles, which can equivalently be seen as a smooth map on $X$ mapping $x$ to this linear map, which gives the best linear approximation to $\Phi$ at $x$. The latter is the common definition in calculus, where $X$ and $Y$ are $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$, as are their tangent spaces.

Comment: Thanks again. The second is becoming more clear for me. I need an example though, suppose that we have `d\psi(t)=\phi(s)\phi(t)` One way is to make sense of this equation using calculus, for a fix `s` this looks fine. The other interpretation is taking `d\psi(t)` as a tangent vector at `\psi(t)` and `\phi(s)`is a group element operating on `d\phi(t)`, a left translation Now given the left-invariant assumption `d\psi` is on the same vector field as is `d\phi`, Right? You see the tangent space operation of differential and its reduction to calculus in one-parameter subgroups is unclear for me.

Comment: @VictorVahidiMotti  It is not really necessary to think in terms of calculus on manifolds in this case. Probably the easiest is to for a curve $\phi:\Bbb R\to G$ (e.g. a one-parameter group) just write $\dot\phi(0)$ rather than $d\phi_0(1)$. They are really the same thing, and the evaluation in other points is not particularly interesting. Also, we are mainly only interested in the derivative in 0, as this maps to $e\in G$, so that the tangent vector to the curve is an element of the Lie algebra.

Comment: The theorem says: for every tangent vector at $e$ there is exactly one one-parameter group mapping $0$ to $e$ and having that vector as its tangent vector in 0. Since tangent vectors correspond to left (or right) invariant vector fields, to each tangent vector there corresponds a unique integral curve. The main point of the proof is to show that an integral curve is in fact a homomorphism.

Comment: See my new question here [link] http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973111/differenational-in-lie-groups